# Best practices for 2D game in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, 2d

I am currently starting the development of a 2D game similar to Lemmings. I am developing it for Windows Phone 7 using only Silverlight. I chose Silverlight for two reasons:

- I create(d) my Graphics using XAML so images don't have to be scaled.
- I may want to port my game to Windows Phone 8 later (which does not support XNA games written in C#.)

Does anyone have any best practices in working with the XAML graphics? For example what's best to keep your graphics lightweight. 
Another problem I have is that I don't have a 'heartbeat' to put the game functionality in. In other words I don't have the 'draw' and 'update' methods that XNA has. Should I just a timer and which one would it be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer your question directly, I would recommend against using silverlight for anything but a trivial game.

What I would recommend is using something more suitable for games like: http://monogame.codeplex.com/

This works exactly like XNA, and works on Windows Phone 8, but also iPhone, android and a host of other platforms.

Comment: I already expected such an answer actually. Do you have a website with an explanation why I should chose XNA instead of Silverlight?

Comment: XNA uses the underlying hardware acceleration directly. While Silverlight is hardware accelerated, but it is difficult to control it. XNA is made for games (gameloops, sprites, 3d, etc), while silverlight is build for UI (event based, markup, higherlevel, etc). On silverlight you'll see performance be ok for a dozen small sprites, but for a game like lemmings where you need a lot of sprites for all the lemming, particle engines for the explosions and deformable backgrounds, silverlight just won't cut it

Comment: http://www.smartypantscoding.com/choosing-between-silverlight-and-xna-for-a-windows-phone-7-game  &  http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/which_product_for_windows_phone

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a simple game for Windows Phone 7 in XAML. The problem I noticed was that the performance drops fast. So if you are doing anything advanced, XNA and Monogame that @Toad is a good idea.

In my game I used timers to update the game, which didn't need to run too often (about 5-10times/second) and then used storyboards for most of the animations and movement in the game. But if you can do that depends on the type of game really.

Some more ideas on how to increase performance in the game:

- Reduce the amount of XAML code
- If using animations, try use only those which can run on the [compositor thread](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-12-13/ui-vs-compositor-demystifying-the-main-windows-phone-7-os-threads.aspx) (GPU acceleration)
- Learn how to use the bitmap cache etc.
- Use the [frame rate counters](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/) and the memory and the [Performance analysis tool](http://debugmode.net/2011/09/17/windows-phone-7-application-performance-analysis/)
- Test on a real device, preferable a first generation device to make sure it run smoothly. The emulator doesn't give that much information on how it will run on a real device.

Some more good links which I found very useful for increasing the performance:

[Windows Phone Performance Part 4 of many– The Power of the GPU](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2012/03/22/windows-phone-performance-part-4-of-many-the-power-of-the-gpu.aspx)

[Performance Considerations in Applications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)